# No matching member function for call to "insert" std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef, unordered-map

I am trying to hash a `string` to a `pointer to a void function which takes in a string`. I get the following error when trying to insert my key value pair into the map:

*"No matching member function for call to "insert"*

I am not sure how to interpret this error.

I think I'm either passing in the wrong type for insert, the function reference incorrectly, or typedef'ing a function pointer wrong.

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

void some_function(string arg)
{
  //some code
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    typedef void (*SwitchFunction)(string);
    unordered_map<string, SwitchFunction> switch_map;

    //trouble with this line
    switch_map.insert("example arg", &some_function); 
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the complete error given?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the overloads for [`std::unordered_map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert), you'll see these:

```
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value );
template< class P >
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( P&& value );
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( value_type&& value );
iterator insert( const_iterator hint, const value_type& value );
template< class P >
iterator insert( const_iterator hint, P&& value );
iterator insert( const_iterator hint, value_type&& value );
template< class InputIt >
void insert( InputIt first, InputIt last );
void insert( std::initializer_list<value_type> ilist );
```

There is no `insert(key_type, mapped_type)`, which is what you're trying to do. What you meant was:

```
switch_map.insert(std::make_pair("example arg", &some_function));
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to place a new entry in the map, without actually making a new entry yourself (aka `std::pair`), then use one of these two forms:

```
switch_map.emplace("example.org", &some_function);
// OR:
switch_map["example.org"] = &some_function;
```

The method `insert` is only for adding PAIRS to the map.
If you need to use insert, then you must make a pair, as [@Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069064/barry) illustrated in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33614032/34824).

Comment: Can you explain how inserting without using pair, is not making a new entry? Not clear how both methods behave with respect to the map. Thank you!

Comment: The new pair is created (obviously); the difference is that ***YOU*** don't have to make the new pair.  The function `emplace` or `[]` does the work for you.  You get to skip calling `std::make_pair`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working fine.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

void some_function(string arg)
{
    return;
  //some code
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
typedef void (*SwitchFunction)(string);


    unordered_map<string, SwitchFunction> switch_map;

    //trouble with this line
    switch_map.insert(std::make_pair("example arg", &some_function));
}
```

You have to use std::make_pair to insert the value.

Comment: Before submitting the solution.. already few people submitted the solution. Have to be fast :P